# What is equivalent of 'mstsc'?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

How to run the equivalent of `mstsc` from an Ubuntu machine (i.e. do a remote login into a Windows EC2 instance)

Answer (score 13):

### Via GUI

Open **dash** and search for **Remmina Remote Desktop Client** or Open terminal( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> )and type `remmina`

Click on New to connect to server. Supported protocols: RDP,SFTP,SSH & VNC

### Via Command line:

To connect to a remote machine via command line. You can use `rdesktop`. To install rdesktop or xrdp use the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install rdesktop
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Usage:

```
rdesktop <machine_name/IP_address>
```