# Remote desktop keeps hanging after connection using Remmina

Tags: remmina

After connecting to my remote desktop, it keeps showing the loading spinner and I can't do anything. I've tried reconnecting, re installing remmina but it still does not work. any idea why this could be happening?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version and trying to access Windows 10 PC.

Comment: Ubuntu release/version?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS @ChanganAuto

Comment: Is that the one you're trying to connect to, from or both? Please always [edit] the question to add information, don't just post it in comments.

Comment: fine - I've edited the post...

Comment: Thank you. Now, if you're trying to access a Windows PC there's a few settings you need to check **in Windows**, like enabling remote desktop access. NOT an Ubuntu question. You may want to post a preferably much more detailed question including the settings on the remote Windows PC at superuser.com.

Comment: Thing is it was working perfectly fine till yesterday and suddenly it started hanging today. Also I dont have access to the windows 10 PC, it belongs to my company. Are you sure this has nothing to do with remmina or Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you access it from a different computer / different OS?

Comment: I couldn't say, haven't tried.

Comment: Some troubleshooting has to be done. Trying from a different environment is the easy way. The "dumb" remote access software hanging one day having worked the day before due to a fault of its own is unheard of. A problem, any problem, with the remote machine or its network is the usual culprit, hence the suggestion to try from somewhere else just to rule out the former possibility. You may want to check this https://askubuntu.com/a/209968/1210606 and try from the command line to see eventual error messages.